# Export windows registry key and strip out some keys

Tags: c++, character-encoding, mingw

I want to export some subkeys from a key in the registry(iterating over it, no problem) into a reg.-file, but I saw that these files are encoded in UCS-2(aka UTF16LE?) with BOM. How can I write a file using this encoding(tried with wofstream and wstring and own BOM but the characters were still 8bit). So how can I convert it right and do I have to mind whether to use the wide or ansi-windows functions in this case?

I am working with mingw/gcc.

Comment: If you need to create a UTF-16 encoded text file on Windows, then yes, use `wofstream` and `wstring`.  And make sure you are using the Unicode versions of Registry functions, not the Ansi versions.

Comment: Do write to `wofstream`, but first `imbue` it with a locale that has `codecvt_utf16` facet installed. See an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I guess I need to use c++0x11 as it is marked as such. But the header codecvt is not available. I am using mingw with gcc version 4.8.1 (tdm-2).

Comment: I gonna check boost for codecvt replacement.